# How to infer information from ccf function in R?

Tags: r

to calculate cross correlation like this

```
   Spend <- c(5, 3, 6, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 12, 11, 10, 9)
   Income <- c(25, 29, 22, 34, 22, 28, 29, 31, 34, 45, 45, 40)
   ccf(Spend, Income,lag.max = 15)
```

now for lag =0

```
  cor(Spend,Income)
  [1] 0.34
  ax=as.numeric(acf(Spend,plot=F)[[1]][2])
  ay=as.numeric(acf(Income,plot=F)[[1]][2])
  ax
  0.62
  ay
  0.52
```

I want to do this for all time series that correspond to all other lags (+-15)

```
          r         ax          ay
 lag0    0.34011   0.6283999   0.52305
 lag1
 lag2
 etc
```

Answer (score 3):

The question seems to be assuming that acf and ccf are symmetric but only the acf is.  This will get you both acf and ccf and show the lags

```
cc <- acf(cbind(Spend, Income))
print(cc)
```

giving the following where the columns that begin with 1.000 are the acf columns.

```
Autocorrelations of series ‘cbind(Spend, Income)’, by lag

, , Spend

 Spend       Income     
  1.000 ( 0)  0.340 ( 0)
  0.628 ( 1)  0.607 (-1)
  0.393 ( 2)  0.730 (-2)
  0.138 ( 3)  0.677 (-3)
 -0.200 ( 4)  0.475 (-4)
 -0.282 ( 5)  0.094 (-5)
 -0.450 ( 6) -0.137 (-6)
 -0.388 ( 7) -0.298 (-7)

, , Income

 Spend       Income     
  0.340 ( 0)  1.000 ( 0)
  0.222 ( 1)  0.523 ( 1)
 -0.040 ( 2)  0.434 ( 2)
 -0.226 ( 3)  0.023 ( 3)
 -0.112 ( 4) -0.013 ( 4)
 -0.333 ( 5) -0.223 ( 5)
 -0.228 ( 6) -0.190 ( 6)
 -0.273 ( 7) -0.264 ( 7)
```

The 3d array can be found in `cc$acf` and the lags in `cc$lag` .  `cc$acf[,1,1]`, `cc$acf[,2,1]`, `cc$acf[,1,2]` and `cc$acf[,2,2]` are the 4 acf/ccf columns and similarly for the lags.